# How to add months in date with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example: I am inserting date 2011-06-01 (format mm/dd/yyyy) and now I want to add 8 months to this date. I want the result to be 2012-02-01.

So when adding months, the year may also increase.

Comment: Thank you, excuse me, improve my questions now :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails provides for + n.days, n.months, etc.

```
my_date + 8.months
```

This is an ActiveRecord, not a Ruby thing, though. So make sure it's loading thru Rails.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the '>>' operator over a Date object to easily achieve just that, it returns a date object N (N being a number) months after the original.

In your case:

```
Date.new(2011,6,1) >> 8
```

That will return the date of 2012-02-01.

Likewise you can use '<<' in order to 'travel back in time'. ;)